# Using decimal.Decimal with sympy

Tags: python, decimal, sympy

I've been trying to create a function that can be used with Decimal class from a sympy expression. I've tried using sympy.utilities.labdify:

```
x = sympy.symbols('x')
expr = sympy.Float('2.3') * x  # same with Decimal('2.3') * x
f = sympy.utilities.lambdify(x, expr)
f(Decimal('1'))
```

This code raises TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'. 
My attempts to change modules in lambdify had no success:

```
x = sympy.symbols('x')
expr = sympy.Float('2.3') * x  # same with Decimal('2.3') * x
my_modules = [{'float': Decimal, 'sympy.core.numbers.Float': Decimal, 'Float': Decimal}, 'numpy']
f = sympy.utilities.lambdify(x, expr, modules=my_modules)
f(Decimal('1'))  # Same error
```

Is it possible to solve this problem and evaluate sympy expressions with decimal.Decimal class as a result?

Comment: `2.3 * decimal.Decimal("1")`, with an ordinary Python float produces the same error.  `lambdify` makes a python function, which you can see with `help(f)`.  The python code, for both cases is just `return 2.3*x`.

Comment: `expr = Decimal('2.3') * x` creates the same `expr` as `2.3*x` or the same with `Float`.  `sympy` doesn't "know" anything about `Decimal`, and thus just uses its `float(Decimal(...))` vaue.